# python music tagger and organiser

Tags: python

i am trying to write a program to read either mp3 or mp4 music files and then print there tags to the screen but the code i have written dose not seem to work and i am completely lost in now to fix it

```
# import mutagen

    from mutagen.easyid3 import EasyID3

    from mutagen.mp4 import MP4

    from mutagen.mp3 import MP3

    # Define a function to read ID3 tags

    MP4 == (audio = MP4(ip))

    MP3 == (Audio = MP3(ip))

    def readid3 (ip):

        if music_file == MP4:

            print(audio['\xa9alb'])
            print(audio['\xa9nam'])
            print(audio['\xa9ART'])
            print(audio['\xa9gen'])


        else:

                if music_file == MP3:

                    print(audio['TALB'])
                    print(audio['TIT2'])
                    print(audio['TPE1'])
                    print(audio['TCON'])


                else:

                    print('Is not a MP3 or MP4 file')



####### main body ########

# prompt user to enter a MP4

    music_file = open('mp4file.txt','a+')
    music_file.write("/Users/martins-mac/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Music/Frightened Rabbit/Pedestrian Verse/01 Acts of Man.m4a")
    music_file.close()

# call function to print ID3 tags

    readid3(music_file)
```

Comment: Please format ur code.

Comment: Please be more specifix about the "dose not seem to work" part.

Answer (score 0):

So these two lines

```
MP4 == (audio = MP4(ip))

MP3 == (Audio = MP3(ip))
```

Are just comparing something.  They'll simply return `True` or `False`, and have no effect.  As it stands, they're just comparing the modules you've imported to an assignment, which is confusing to me.  What were you trying to do with those lines?

```
if music_file == MP4:
```

Is the correct way to use `==`, but `music_file` is not defined at this point.  When you call it later on, it's defined globally, but it looks like

```
if ip == MP4:
```

Would serve you better.

When you get down to `readid3(music_file)`, you've already closed the file.  Try putting `music_file = open("mp4file.txt", "r")` before that line.

You may also be well-served to check out https://mutagen.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/base.html, as there are bound to be some useable examples in there.

Comment: Thank you this has helped a lot .